# Как сделать команду с аргументом в Telebot(Python) Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

Вот пример::
/command <команда >

Answer (score 4):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["command"]) # В commands может быть несколько разных команд
def answer(message):
    command = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1] # В переменной будет всё, что идёт после /command
```

Comment: command = message.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: добавил исправление в ответ - `message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

В telebot.utils есть метод extract_arguments(). На вход он принимает текст сообщения (надо передать), а на выход возвращает весь текст сообщения кроме команды

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]