# передача значения команды telebot

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
import random

token = '167...:AAF...KhA'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "привет")


@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def main_sender(message):
    if message.text == "привет":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'end')



bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

мне нужно чтоб после слова привет пользователь вводил число или букву и она потом применялась в будующем к примеру пользователь ввел "привет 3" и привет выведется в консоль 3 раза или "привет й" и случайная буква в слове привет изменится на й, опять же это к примеру, мне нужно понять только как передавать параметр с сообщением чтоб оно записывалось к примеру как в переменную, и как переменную значение параметра можно было использовать, или что то вроде этого

Comment: Делайте `split` сообщения и затем формируйте нужный вам ответ

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229952/234134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def start(message):
    if 'привет' in message.text.lower():
        arg = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
        if arg.isdigit():  # если "аргумент" цифра
            for _ in range(0, int(arg)):  # "привет 3" и "привет" выведется в консоль 3(arg) раз
                print(message.text[:-2])
        else:
            inds = [i for i, _ in enumerate(message.text[:-2]) if not message.text[:-2].isspace()]
            sam = random.sample(inds, 3)

            lst = list(message.text[:-2])
            for ind in sam:
                lst[ind] = random.choice(ascii_letters)

            print("".join(lst))  # заменить 3 символа в сообщении клиента
```