# pyTelegramBotAPI + openpyxl

Tags: python, telebot, openpyxl

Пишу телеграмм бот на pyTelegramBotAPI, одной из команды которого будет при запросе пользователя в группе выводить IP компьютеров, которые взяты из таблички Excel (брать должен по почтовому индексу). Табличка состоит из строк почтового индекса, адреса, IP и т.д. Сейчас он все это делает, только вводится индекс сейчас в терминал Pycharm. Суть вопроса возможно ли команду бота 'pc' добавить неизвестную переменную f'pc{user_index}'. Какие есть варианты, чтобы индекс не с консоли вводился? Прослушивать просто текст и когда введут индекс например 73008 не совсем вариант, потому что бот будет в группе где могут с другим вопросом это писать. Варианты, которые я представляю:

1. Чтобы после команды /pc бот спросил индекс, и только после команды /pc начал прослушивать текст и пользователь ввел индекс в это время.
2. Если возможно в саму команду /pc добавить переменную индекса.

Main:

```
import telebot
import openxml

bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxx')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['pc'])
def pc(message):
    openxml.pc_vpz()
    for i in openxml.pc_result:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, openxml.pc_result)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Файл поиска IP по файлу Excel:

```
import openpyxl

def pc_vpz():
    book = openpyxl.open('Ip_PC.xlsx', read_only=True)
    global pc_result
    pc_result = []
    sheet = book.active
    user_index = int(input('Введите индекс:'))
    count_pc = 0

    for row in range(2, 50):
        index = sheet[row][1].value
        ip_pc = sheet[row][3].value

        if index and ip_pc:
            if user_index == index:
                pc_result.append(ip_pc)
                count_pc += 1

        elif not index and count_pc == 0:
            print('Такого отделения не найдено')
            break

    return pc_result
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229952/234134

Comment: @bot.message_handler(commands=['pc'])
def pc_ip(message):
    pc = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
    openxml.pc_vpz()
    for i in openxml.pc_result:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, openxml.pc_result)                                                                         
Не вдуплю, как теперь pc впихнуть в файл поиска ип ексель(openxml) вместо user_index = int(input('Введите индекс:')).

Comment: user_index = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1]

Comment: После отправки команды /pc в телеге ничего не происходит, скрока что написали user_index = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1] во втором файле так и остается или кочует в мейн файл? Лепил и ту да и туда, ничего не выводит. Если я ввожу например /pc73008 оно сохраняет 73008 в user_index? Пробовал через принт проверять, внутри ничего нет, как это работает..

Comment: `openxml.pc_vpz(message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1])` (ещё раз посмотрите пример по первой ссылке), `def pc_vpz(user_index)` и закомментируйте `user_index = int(input('Введите индекс:'))`

Comment: Спасибо!)) Я не правильно просто команду писал не /pc73008, а с пробелом.../pc 73008